# How do i change my keyboard locale?

Tags: iphone, ios4

Can i change my keyboard locale programatically.

I have searched for solution on web and found that we have to customize the keyboard for changing the language.

Any hints or links would help me to start.

Comment: enjoy your up Vote and your answer

Comment: the locale of keyboard is managed by the user. programatically you cannot force your mind of keyboard layout to the user. however you can customise the current keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah You have to Customize  the keyboard. But there is an one option you can change your keyboard in iPhone in any language. just by click on settings->General->Keyboard->International Keyboard->Add new Keyboard...... add any language you want.....But in Application when the keyboard will open click on Globe and then select any keyboard